# How to update a Table of Tables with macro vba-Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm a beginner in word-vba macros (but I quite good for excel-vba) and I'm looking to update a "Table of Tables". 
I've found out how to do so for "Table of Content" and "Table of Figures" (with `ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents(1).Update`) but the Collection TableOfTables doesn't exist. 
Does someone know what I have to do?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a "Table of Tables" object or a TableOfTables collection. A "Table of Tables" is really just a kind of "Table of Contents". Indeed, so too is a "Table of Figures". If you look at the field codes underlying these, you'll see all three use a TOC field - a "Table of Tables" and a "Table of Figures" would have field codes like { TOC \h \z \c "Table" } and { TOC \h \z \c "Figure" }, respectively. So, if you want to update any of these (or any custom types you create), but not necessarily all, you can simply loop through the TableOfContents collection and check what follows the \c switch, if present. Likewise, you can loop through the TableOfContents collection and update all items in it. Hence:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim TOC As TableOfContents
For Each TOC In ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents
  TOC.Update
  'Or depending on what you want to update:
  'TOC.UpdatePageNumbers
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

A simpler way - for all fields - would be:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument
  .Fields.Update
  .PrintPreview
  .ClosePrintPreview
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I don't realy understand this sentence 
_'If you look at the field codes underlying these'_
what do you mean? How can I access this code?

Moreover, when you mentioned _lopoping  through the TableOfContents collection_, I imagine I'll have to use something like 

`For k=1 to X
    ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents(k).update
Next k`
However, it only works with `k=1`
If I check with `Count` I can see that there is only one item in this collection

Comment: Word uses objects called fields to maintain Tables of Contents, cross-references and so on. You can toggle the field code display on/off via Alt-F9. With it toggled 'on', you can see the code that drives what is displayed. As for the TablesOfContents collection containing only one item, that suggests you don't have a separate "Table of Tables".

Comment: all right, I'll keep all of that in the back of my mind ;)
Thanks again. As you can see in my other post, it helps me a lot

Answer (score 3):

Ok, thanks to @macropod I figured out how to solve my issue.
The 'Table of tables' is not another table of content but another table of **figures**
So here is my finale code :

```
Public Sub UpdateAllFiles()
    With ActiveDocument
        .TablesOfContents(1).Update
        .TablesOfFigures(1).Update
        .TablesOfFigures(2).Update
    End With
End Sub
```